# How can I make two varchar fields in a table a primary key?

Tags: mysql, innodb, composite-primary-key

MySQL
Engine: InnoDB

I have a table, and I need two strings as primary key.
The reason for this is because I want ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE depended on those two strings.
How do I do that?
Ty in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use them as primary keys. Use them as `UNIQUE` indices instead, and `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will still work. I would advise that you set your primary key to be a single integer type column that is completely independent of your data.

Have a look at this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41f2d/1

Comment: So if they are `UNIQUE` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE still works?
And something more... there can be duplicates of the same data in those fields, just not the same combination. Any suggestions?? or MySQL code?

Comment: @DeusDeceit Yes, it works in pretty much exactly the same way as a primary key conflict would.

Comment: How can I combine two fields as UNIQUE?

Comment: @DeusDeceit When using the `UNIQUE` clause, put multiple column names in the brackets. eg. `UNIQUE(a,b,c)` ensures all combinations of columns a, b and c are unique.

Comment: @DeusDeceit See the example.

Answer (score 1):

you can alter table and define that two columns as primary key,

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD PRIMARY KEY (colA, colB);
```

or during creation of the table

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
    colA INT, 
    colB INT,
    -- other fields here, ....
    CONSTRAINT tb_pk PRIMARY KEY (colA, colB)
)
```

Comment: Can a foreign key also be inside a composite-primary-key?